# Laravel 4 relationship between user and friend tables

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have two tables `users` and `friends`. How can I write out all friends of user with userID (1) ?
Which relationship should I use?

**User.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = array('email', 'username', 'password', 'password_temp', 'code', 'active', 'remember_token');



    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    public function friends()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Friend');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


}
```

**Friend.php**

```
<?php


class Friend extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('friend_one', 'friend_two', 'status');




    protected $table = 'friends';
  public function users() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
       }


}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function getFriendShow(){
        $cur_login = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $friends = $cur_login->friends;

        return View::make('profile.friends')->with('friends', $friends);

    }
```

**friends.blade.php**

```
     <ul>
        @foreach($friends as $friend)
        <li><a href="">{{  }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Controller to

```
public function getFriendShow(){

        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $friends = Friend::where('userID','=', "4")->get();

        return View::make('profile.friends')->with('friends', $friends);

    }
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: How can I write out all friends using username from users table ?

Comment: In the code above, it grabs all the friends for the current logged in user.  Did you have a different intention?

Comment: This will write out record from friend table wherein is sth like:
{"id":26,"friend_one":4,"friend_two":4,"status":"1","created_at":"2014-11-29 16:37:22","updated_at":"2014-11-29 16:37:22"} and I want use user's username which id is 4

Comment: Is this what you mean?